# Javascript/PHP/Jquery - Autofill and Data Encryption

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

I am looking for a better autocomplete function / handling or a way to encode specific data from source view.

I have a MYSQL Database with Customer Information as such:

```
 Record | CompanyName | StreetAddress | City | State | Zip   | Telephone
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1   |  Eatery     |  123 Main St  |  NYC |   NY  | 10001 |  000-000-0000
------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
    2   |  Jo's Gym   |  456 2nd St   |  NYC |   NY  | 10001 | 000-000-0000
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
etc....
```

I then have a search page to search for customers. This search page has a text input box to grab all CompanyName into an array:

```
while( $row = $results->fetch_assoc() )
{
    array_push($customerArray,$row['companyname']);
}
```

Then I utilize the jquery autocomplete function located here ( http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ )

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($customerArray); ?>;
        $( "#customername" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
</script>
```

Which does work correctly by autocomplete-ing my input box

```
<label for="customername">Customer Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="companyname" id="customername" size="30">
<span id="customernamespan"></span>
```

So all is working great. I even have javascript validation to make sure the customer being entered is in the list

My issue with the following is that the 5000+ CustomerName is now in an array visible for all who checks the source code.

Is there any way to hide this info or is there a better approach to the autocomplete?

---

I am thinking the only real way to handle this is to have a intermediate page validate customer name and echo back "best guesses".

addnotes.php will have fields and CustomerName will be regular text input box.

checkCustomer.php would have all data in $_POST and query MySQL DB for CustomerName LIKE %token%token% and echo back with radio buttons with a "did you mean this" header. If it is any of them then they can select the name or click add new customer.

If name clicked, then pass $_POST to handleaddnotes.php and do my work with inserts and yada yada

If new client, pass $_POST to createCustomer.php and create new customer and then process the original addnotes $_POST

--

Thanks,
eherr

Comment: As a suggestion you can check using AJAX, so it limits the result to what PHP returns and the calls are asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

What I do in those cases is wait until the user types 3 or more characters in the input, then, launch an ajax request retrieving the list of records matching the first characters...

```
<input type="text" name="companyname" id="customername" size="30" onchange="autofill(this.value);">



<script type = "text/javascript">
   function autofill(text){
      if ( text.length < 3 ) return;
      else  ajax.post("get_customers.php", {data:text}, function(response){
          $( "#customername" ).autocomplete({
            source: response.availableTags
        });
      });
   }
</script>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be more about the Usability than the code.

1. If you encrypt autocomplete data, how will your user use the autocomplete function?
2. If you approach the problem with a LIKE solution, typing "a" and asking the back-end to retrieve the options for you will fall into pretty much the same problem.
3. If your user can't see your autocomplete data, then autocomplete might not be what you're looking for.

Try to revalidate your goal:

1. What is your true goal?
2. Why do your user have to select an option?
3. What is more important about this data? Security or Usability?
4. Are there any other ways that your user can grab all customers name inside your software?